# NSFW text in an image?

Tags: discussion

[Dataflow Profiles](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21678/dataflow-profiles)

First, I am not sure the image is all that necessary here (in the first answer), but is there a precedent for not displaying images with naughty text?  I am not worried about my workplace, but I can see some rather nanny-ish places having a problem with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this particular example crosses any line, not by a long shot -- otherwise we'd have to start burning office coffee table Cosmopolitans.

People who actually feel offended by such things should steer clear from e-commerce in general. Seriously, is there anything they don't sell on internet nowadays? Somebody had to build their stores ... from their perspective it was suitable for work well enough.

Comment: No argument from me, I figured better to ask than move along in apathy

Comment: There's actually another, somwhat related question that probably requires separate topic -- is it ok to display materials what might or might not be sensitive from customer perspective? You know, even if you haven't signed NDA with customer, it doesn't automatically mean that you can post their stuff to inter-tubes for whole world to see.

Comment: Pronto you are right, I'm actually surprised I didn't look at this from that angle...

Answer (score 1):

Well, tricky question. I guess this particular example almost crossed the line but still can be kept.